# Windows環境上のBitnami RedmineでSubversionのリポジトリログを再取得（更新）するには

Tags: svn, redmine

チケットコメントを間違えたときに、Subversionのhookにてログの修正を下記のとおりpre-revprop-change.batを用いて変更したのですが

```
if "%5"=="M" (
  if "%4"=="svn:log" (
    exit 0
  )
)
echo "Changing revision properties other than svn:log is prohibited" >&2
exit 1
```

リポジトリログ自体は修正されているものの、Redmineではこの方法で修正したリポジトリログを再取得（更新）してくれません。 
おそらくpre-revprop-change.batではなく、post-revprop-change.batを使用するとは思うのですが、Redmine上で正しく再取得出来るhookスクリプトはどのように記述したらよいでしょうか。